# This deplyment error occurs when I use Connect signal and slots

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, connect

when I execute like this at Desktop it works fine but when try to deploy on remote device then error occurs.

```
connect(ui->lineEdit, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, this, [=]()->void
{
    QString str = ui->lineEdit->text();
    qDebug()<<"Input (HEX) = " << str;
    bool ok;
    int iVal = str.toInt(&ok,16);
    QString binnumber = str.setNum(iVal, 2);
    if(ok)
        ui->lineEdit_2->setText(binnumber);
    else
        ui->lineEdit_2->setText("Not a number");
    qDebug()<<"output in binary = " << binnumber;
});
```

errors:

```
1).
/usr/local/Qt-4.8.7-arm/include/QtGui/qlineedit.h:196: error: ‘void QLineEdit::textEdited(const QString&)’ is protected
     void textEdited(const QString &);
          ^
2). 
/home/ijaz/Qt_applications/update_automatically/mainwindow.cpp:24: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
     });
     ^
3).
/home/ijaz/Qt_applications/update_automatically/mainwindow.cpp:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘MainWindow::connect(QLineEdit*&, void (QLineEdit::*)(const QString&), MainWindow* const, MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::__lambda0)’
     });
      ^
```

Comment: It seems you are using a different version of Qt on your remote device (Qt-4.8.7 instead of Qt5)

Comment: Please, note: The kind of `connect()` you are using is introduced with Qt5. [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax). Hence, it wouldn't surprise me that you don't get it compiled for Qt-4.8.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's shown on the error message, your target device has Qt on this path `/usr/local/Qt-4.8.7-arm` which shows that the Qt version is 4.8.7. [Lambda expressions on signal/slot need Qt 5](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) and is not available on Qt 4.8.7. Either update Qt version on your target device or do your desktop development on the same version as used on your target embedded device.